# attribute is not recorded in serialization arraylist

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

When I do serialization with this code, I got a null pointer exception with 'managerL.get(1).getID()'. I am sure that it is serialized as an object as 'managerL.size()' return 1. When I try to open manager.ser with HxD, I cannot find any of my objects attribute. Am I doing it wrong? How to solve it?

So here is my code:

```
            List <manager>managerL=null;
            manager NEW=new manager(nID,nName,nPW);
            managerL.add(NEW);
            try{
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream("manager.ser");
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);
                out.writeObject(managerL); //write NEW into manager.ser
                out.close(); 
                fOut.close();
                System.out.println("new user is able to login, try and see~");
            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }
```

Comment: managerL.size() == 1 means element 0 will exist but element 1 will not.

Comment: show ur Manager class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements in List are indexed starting from 0 and 1.

Need to modify code as `managerL.get(0).getXXX()`

`managerL.get(1)` will throw NPE

Answer (score 0):

`List#get(1)` will work if the list size is at least 2. Your list has only 1 object. You should be doing `.get(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use managerL.get(0) as there is only 1 item.